# creating multiple folders using excel VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

```
Sub Datasheet_MC_V1()
'
' Datasheet_MC_V1 Macro
'
Dim Filemane As String

n = Sheets("Loop").Range("C1").Value
For i = 2 To n + 1

    Sheets("Loop").Select
    Range("A" & i).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("For Looping").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Filename = Cells(2, 2).Value
    x = "Multicopter\"
    MkDir "C:\Users\Raam\Desktop\Excel marcro for datasheet\" & Filename
    Sheets("Before display").Select
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\Raam\Desktop\Excel marcro for datasheet\" & Filename & "\" & Filename & "_datasheet.pdf" _
        , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
        :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

    Next i


End Sub
```

I'm trying to save the file as pdf in the folder created based on the cell value I'm getting error.

I'm not getting an error when the code is

```
   ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\Raam\Desktop\Excel marcro for datasheet\"  & Filename & "_datasheet.pdf" _
```

i.e when I try to save it outside the created folder.

Comment: Well, what's the error?

Comment: run time error '1004':
the document may have been open or an error may have been encountered while saving

Comment: Sorry... 
the problem is with the value in the cell..If i choose different cell with a normal numbers it is working fine.
The name of the file should be 17 x 5,7 P, but it shows error.. Is there any way to fix it...

But i can save using that file name (17 x 5,7 P ) if i choose to save outside that folder

Comment: @RaamSundhar, welcome to Super User,, please [Edit] your post & be specific your need, bcoz in above code no where U have use command to create FOLDER,,, below you have written that you are trying to save the file !!

Comment: @RajeshS *"command to create FOLDER"* The `MkDir` statement creates a new Folder.

Comment: @RaamSundhar Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce your problem with the information provided.  When I create a new folder on my desktop, using your code and your suggested file name, it works.See [Excel: VBA to print to PDF - Run time error 1004](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17379700/excel-vba-to-print-to-pdf-run-time-error-1004) for ideas.  There are also multiple other threads both on SO and elsewhere with similar problem and solutions.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld,, yes that I know,,, the MKDIR,, now I found it withing the code,, is my fault,, I'm sure OP is using wrong command, it shout `MkDir "C:\Filoder1\Folder2\Examples"` or `VBA.MkDir (the path)`,, but not like `x = "Multicopter\" MkDir "C:\Users\`    !!

Comment: @RajeshS Here it looks like those statements are on two separate lines.  And I don't see where he is using the variable `x`, but that shouldn't be causing his problem.

Comment: Hi everyone...
Thank you so much for the help...
I found the mistake.. The mistake was in the name of the file. It had an empty space at the end of the text which was causing the problem...

Comment: @RaamSundhar,,, post the solution as an answer with the modified code line,,, you may earn some up votes too ☺

Comment: Thank you so much everyone.. This is my first question in Stacks and I'm really glad seeing so many people trying to help.. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Datasheet_MC_V1()

' Datasheet_MC_V1 Macro

 Dim Filemane As String

n = Sheets("Loop").Range("C1").Value

For i = 2 To n + 1
Sheets("Loop").Select

Range("A" & i).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("For Looping").Select
Range("A2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Filename = Cells(4, 2).Value
MkDir "C:\Users\Raam\Desktop\Excel marcro for datasheet\" & Filename
Sheets("Before display").Select

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\Raam\Desktop\Excel marcro for datasheet\" & Filename & "\" & Filename & "_datasheet.pdf" _
    , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

Next i
End Sub
```

in the cell (4,2) I used the formula TRIM (2,2) this removes the empty spaces that were there which was the cause of the error.
Filename = Cells(4, 2).Value

So this program creates a directory with the filename (in a specific cell) and creates a saves as a pdf in the name of filename_datasheet.pdf in the created folder.

Comment: Nice one @Ram Sundhar ,,, +10 ☺